# How to return a list of strings from a function?

Tags: javascript

How to pass a list of strings from a function? I  am calling an endpoint. for the time being, I will mock the API and return a list of strings.  I got stuck here. can anyone help me?

```
mock.onGet('/patients/100/advanced-graphings').reply(200, {
  advancedGraphing: '[ "Graph 1" , "Graph 2" , "Graph 3" , "Graph 4" , "Graph 5" , "Graph 6" ]'
});
```

Comment: You need an array, example : const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the single quotes from your `advancedGraphing` object value.

```
mock.onGet('/patients/100/advanced-graphings').reply(200, {
  advancedGraphing: [ "Graph 1" , "Graph 2" , "Graph 3" , "Graph 4" , "Graph 5" , "Graph 6" ]
});
```